# How can I combine multiple "js files" into one dynamically using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

This function below integrates js functions into the web app, while passing multiple values as an object, but how can I add more functions (`approval_tracker_js`, for instance), which would be another file dynamically?
The reason for this is to keep these files short and easy to maintain rather than having such a long `ap_dashboard_js`:

```
const getNewPageContent = (clientType, clientName, clientId, userId, userFirstName, userLastName) => {
  if (clientType === "AP") {
    const apDashboardJs = "ap_dashboard_js";
    const approvalTrackerJs = "approval_tracker_js";

      let apDahboardHtml = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(apDashboardJs);
      apDahboardHtml.obj = {
        clientType: clientType,
        clientName: clientName,
        clientId: clientId,
        userFirstName: userFirstName,
        userLastName: userLastName
      };

      const apDashboardHtml2Content = apDahboardHtml.evaluate().getContent();
      const apDashboardHtmlWindow = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("ap_dashboard");
      apDashboardHtmlWindow[apDashboardJs] = apDashboardHtml2Content;

      return apDashboardHtmlWindow.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL).getContent();
    });
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('ok');
}
```

Comment: If want multiple files in one then just create them that way. You can reorganize functions with apps script api but I have found dealing with individual functions is a lot more difficult then dealing with pages of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

Unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation. So, this is just my guess.

#### Prerequisites:

As prerequisites, your Google Apps Script project has 4 files as follows.

- `Code.gs`: Google Apps Script including your showing script.
- `ap_dashboard_js.html`: This HTML file has Javascript.
- `approval_tracker_js.html` This HTML file has Javascript.
- `ap_dashboard.html`: This HTML file is the main HTML.

When your situation is the above, how about the following sample script?

#### `Code.gs`

```js
const getNewPageContent = (clientType, clientName, clientId, userId, userFirstName, userLastName) => {
  if (clientType === "AP") {
    const apDashboardJs = "ap_dashboard_js";
    const approvalTrackerJs = "approval_tracker_js";
    let apDahboardHtml = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(apDashboardJs);
    apDahboardHtml.obj = JSON.stringify({
      clientType: clientType,
      clientName: clientName,
      clientId: clientId,
      userFirstName: userFirstName,
      userLastName: userLastName
    });
    const apDashboardHtml2Content = apDahboardHtml.evaluate().getContent();
    const apDashboardHtmlWindow = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("ap_dashboard");
    apDashboardHtmlWindow[apDashboardJs] = apDashboardHtml2Content;
    apDashboardHtmlWindow[approvalTrackerJs] = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(approvalTrackerJs).getContent();
    return apDashboardHtmlWindow.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL).getContent();
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('ok');
}

// This is a sample for confirming the result value.
function sample() {
  const res = getNewPageContent("AP", "clientName", "clientId", "userId", "userFirstName", "userLastName");
  console.log(res);
}
```

#### `ap_dashboard_js.html`

```html
<script>
const sample = "ap_dashboard_js.html";
const obj = <?!= obj ?>;

// do something
</script>
```

- Please put your Javascript in the tag of `<script>`.
- I cannot know the method for using `obj`. So, I modified it as the above. In this case, the object of `obj` can be used in Javascript.

#### `approval_tracker_js.html`

```html
<script>
const sample = "approval_tracker_js.html";

// do something
</script>
```

- Please put your Javascript in the tag of `<script>`.

#### `ap_dashboard.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= ap_dashboard_js ?>
    <?!= approval_tracker_js ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>ap_dashboard.html</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Testing

When the function `sample()` is run, the following result is obtained.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script>
    const sample = "ap_dashboard_js.html";
    const obj = {"clientType":"AP","clientName":"clientName","clientId":"clientId","userFirstName":"userFirstName","userLastName":"userLastName"};
  </script>
  <script>
    const sample = "approval_tracker_js.html";
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>ap_dashboard.html</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Note:

- In your showing script, the returned value is `return apDashboardHtmlWindow.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL).getContent();`. It's a text data of the HTML. From this situation, I also used it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you want, but using Templated HTML you could include each function file into one HTML content.

**Code.gs**

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function showTest() {
  html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('HTML_Test').evaluate();
  console.log(html.getContent());
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Test');
}
```

**Function1.html**

```
function function1() {
  let name = "this is Function1";
}
```

**Function2.html**

```
function function2() {
  let name = "this is Function2";
}
```

**Function3.html**

```
function function3() {
  let name = "this is Function3";
}
```

**HTML_Test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello
    <script>
      <?!= include('Function1'); ?>
      <?!= include('Function2'); ?>
      <?!= include('Function3'); ?>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Resulting HTML Content**

```
Dec 29, 2023, 1:56:21 PM    Debug   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello
    <script>
      function function1() {
  let name = "this is Function1";
}
      function function2() {
  let name = "this is Function2";
}
      function function3() {
  let name = "this is Function3";
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```